# How to solve Var out of scope within setTimeout call

Tags: javascript, scope

I am trying to call a setTimeout from within a setInterval callback:

```
function callback()
{
   //assign myVar
   var myVar = document.getElementById("givenID");
   //...
   //now wait 2 secs then call some code that uses myVAr
   setTimeout("myVar.innerHTML = 'TEST'", 2000);
}

setInterval("callback();", 10000);
```

setInterval works as expected but setTimeout call is failing. I guess the problem is related to the fact that I am referencing a variable (myVar) that's not in scope.

What's the best way to solve this?

Comment: It seems to work for me. What do you mean by "failing"? And what browser/etc. are you using?

Comment: Alert was working for me too with previous example - so the problem is not related to the setTimeout in there, thanks for pointing out, I edited the question.

Comment: Using closures like I indicated below would work around this, the inner closure has access to the outer closures scope.

Comment: I must be missing something - are you trying to save some performance by precalculating myVar? Why not

setTimeout("document.getElementById("givenID").innerHTML = 'TEST'", 2000);

?

Comment: Don't use quotes with setTimout/setInterval, it forces the JS runtime to invoke Eval, which runs the code in a new context, hence the scope issue.

Comment: Cheers to everyone - I learned a lot of stuff from this question

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is a perfect candidate for closures:

```
setInterval(
    function ()
    {
       var myVar = document.getElementById("givenID");
       setTimeout(
          function()
          {
              // myVar is available because the inner closure 
              // gets the outer closures scope
              myVar.innerHTML = "Junk";
          },2000);
    }, 10000);
```

Your problem is scope related, and this would work around that.

Comment: Thus illustrating an excellent reason not to pass strings as parameters to setTimeout and setInterval! :-)

Comment: This is great news - it seems in every example of SetTimeout and SetInterval the parameter is a string; didn't know you could just pass in a closure.

Comment: this is a REALLY good candidate for a those closure tutorials that are so popular at the moment....

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem. The issue was that I was trying to call a method from within itself through a setTimeout(). Something like this, WHICH DIDN'T WORK FOR ME:

```
function myObject() {

   this.egoist = function() {
      setTimeout( 'this.egoist()', 200 );
   }

}

myObject001 = new myObject();
myObject001.egoist();
```

The following ALSO DIDN'T WORK:

```
... setTimeout( egoist, 200 );
... setTimeout( egoist(), 200 );
... setTimeout( this.egoist, 200 );
... setTimeout( this.egoist(), 200 );
... setTimeout( function() { this.egoist() }, 200 );
```

The solution was to use with() statement like so:

```
function myObject() {

   this.egoist = function() {
      with (this) { setTimeout( function() { egoist() }, 200 );}
   }

}

myObject001 = new myObject();
myObject001.egoist();
```

Of course, this is an endless cycle, but the point I'm making here is different.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 4):

As a matter of best-practice, try not to use strings as parameters to `setTimeout` and `setInterval` because that will invoke `eval` ... Using the following form might also make this problem easier to understand/debug:

```
setInterval(function () {
    // do stuff
    // ...
    // now wait 2 secs then call someFunction
    setTimeout(someFunction, 2000);
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Run it in Firefox and check Tools | Error Console.  if setTimeout fails it may tell you why there.

Also, try replacing `"someFunction();"` with `"alert('hi')"` (no semicolon) and see if that works.  If so, the problem is narrowed down significantly.

Comment: cheers - I did this and noticed the problem wasn't related to setTimeout - see edit