# How to call a function that is stored in a set of options from within setTimeout() inside an AJAX callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here's my relevant code:

```
success: [
             setTimeout(function () {
                    ajax.success
             }, 250),
         //...
```

The strange thing is that I can call `ajax.success` from within the `success: []` option, however it stops working when wrapped in `setTimeout()`.

What I think would work best is assigning the `ajax.success` option to a function right before this code gets executed, however I'm not sure how to do so.

Any help is greatly appreciated, and my apologies if this is a duplicate. I couldn't find something similar.

Comment: Could you post the whole ajax call? `success: [` looks invalid.

Comment: ajax.success is a function reference, setTimeout returns undefined. Therefore in one case you are passing a function reference, and in another your are passing undefined. That is why it works one way and not the other.

Comment: @bfavaretto from the api: *"As of jQuery 1.5, the success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn."*

Comment: why did you additionally wrap `ajax.success` in an anonymous `function()`. Try `setTimeout(ajax.success, 250);`. Also I am pretty sure your success paramter needs to use `{}` instead of `[]`.

Comment: @keyCrumbs simply put, you can't put a settimeout where you placed it. Instead, create an anonymous function and place the setTimeout inside of it, see Code Monkey's answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237350/how-to-solve-var-out-of-scope-within-settimeout-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`success` callback accepts a handler or a list of handlers. However the result of calling `setTimeout` is a unique ID associated with that timeout. It's not a function. Thus what you probably want is:

```
success: [
    function() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            doStuff();
        }, 250),
    },
    // ...
]
```

If your function needs to use some args, then you can wrap it like that:

```
success: [
    function() {
        var self = this,
            args = arguments;

        setTimeout(function () {
            doStuff.apply(self, args);
        }, 250),
    },
    // ...
]
```

Note that `this` and `arguments` are keywords. Also note the use of `.apply`.

Comment: @keyCrumbs Have you tried the code I've posted after the update? Perhaps the problem is in the function itself.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you mean to do?...

```
function doWork() {
console.log('test');
}

$.ajax({
    url: 'xxx',
    success: function() {
     setTimeout(function() {
        doWork();
      }, 1000);
     }
});
```

Comment: Nice, but you've got an extra anonymous function there.

Comment: Put a console.log('testing') inside your doWork() function to make sure that it is even getting called. Try moving the definition of doWork() to a higher level up (Global scope) outside of document.ready: //try defining it here instead  $(function() { //do not define it here   });