# setTimeout not working setted to 30000, but not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like this:

```
var isAnimating = 'no';
$('.big-slider-button img').click(function(e){

                if(isAnimating=='no')
                    {
                    isAnimating = 'yes';
                    setTimeout(isAnimating = 'no',30000);
                var img_nr = $(this).attr('description');
                if(img_nr!='0')
                {
                    var image = $('.billboard').attr('src');
                    var new_image = (image.substr(0,image.length-9))+img_nr+"-big.png";
                    $(".billboard").fadeOut(1000, function() {
                        $(this).attr('src',new_image);
                        $('.big-slider-button img').attr('description',parseInt(img_nr)-1);
                        $('.big-slider-button-right img').attr('description',parseInt(img_nr)+1);
                    }).fadeIn(1000);
                }}

            });
```

but it's not working. I set timeout on 30000 on purpose to see if it's working but it's not. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? Thank you all in advance for your help.

EDIT: THANK YOU ALL FOR YOUR ANSWERS. I'M A BIT NEW WITH JQUERY, SO SORRY IF MY QUESTION IS STUPID.

Comment: No research effort... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)

```
 setTimeout(function(){ isAnimating = 'no' },30000);
```

Answer (score 6):

you need to pass a callback function

```
setTimeout(function(){
    isAnimating = 'no'
},30000);
```

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to setTimeout is a piece of code you want to run when the specified amount of time has passed. In Javascript, units of executable code have to be passed as functions, so you'll want to create a function that does whatever you want to do in 30s.

```
setTimeout(function(){ isAnimating = 'no'; }, 30000);
```

You can also simply pass the name of a function (without parenthesis) to have it execute after the timeout, like so:

```
doStuff = function(){ isAnimating = 'no'; };
setTimeout(doStuff , 30000);
```

Also, be sure that isAnimating is global, if you're hoping to set a local variable on an object using this method, you'll need some way to access it from the global scope. Check out this Q&A for more information about scopes and closures: [How to solve Var out of scope within setTimeout call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237350/how-to-solve-var-out-of-scope-within-settimeout-call)

Hope this helps!